# bash variables in for loop range

Tags: bash, for

I want to print list of numbers from 1 to 100 and I use a for loop like the following:

```
number=100
for num in {1..$number}
do
  echo $num
done
```

When I execute the command it only prints {1..100} and not the list of number from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, that's because brace-expansion occurs before parameter expansion. Either use another shell like `zsh` or `ksh93` or use an alternative syntax:

#### Standard (POSIX) sh syntax

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$number" ]; do
  echo "$i"
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

#### Ksh-style `for ((...))`

```
for ((i=1;i<=number;i++)); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

#### use `eval` (not recommended)

```
eval '
  for i in {1..'"$number"'}; do
    echo "$i"
  done
'
```

#### use the GNU `seq` command on systems where it's available

```
unset -v IFS # restore IFS to default
for i in $(seq "$number"); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

(that one being less efficient as it forks and runs a new command and the shell has to reads its output from a pipe).

#### Avoid loops in shells.

Using loops in a shell script are often an indication that you're not doing it right.

Most probably, your code can be written some other way.

Comment: I used `seq 1 $number` and it is working in bash.

Comment: That's off-topic, but I have to ask anyway: What is the problem with loops in shells? Why is it bad to use them?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'avoid loops in shells' part please, if you have any example? I use for all the time. for i in `ls`... do something for that name.

Comment: [Why do you recommend avoiding loops in shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198639/avoid-loops-in-shells)? There are common cases of loop abuse, such as using `while read` instead of sed/awk/…, or looping over the output of `find` instead of using `-exec`. But a blanket “avoid loops in shells” is going too far.

Comment: @Gilles, could you elaborate? I'm very interested in any times you can think of when a loop in a shell *would* be the right tool, because from this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/135943 I had pretty much concluded there weren't any.  (See the last line in that answer.)  At least, *I* can't think of any cases where it would be the best tool.

Comment: @Wildcard For example, to process a list of files obtained from wildcard patterns, or to iterate over array elements. The answer you link is about processing texts, and even then there are cases where a `while read` loop is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 8):

You don't even need a for loop for this, just use the `seq` command:

```
$ seq 100
```

#### Example

Here's the first 10 numbers being printed out:

```
$ seq 100 | head -10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: or `seq $number` if you want to assign some integer to `$number`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
for (( num=1; num <= 100; num++ ))
do
    echo $num
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it simply in Bash script (and that looks like what you were doing)

```
number=100
for num in $(seq 1 $number); do
    echo $num;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The brace expansion only works for literal integers or single characters. It happens before variable expansion, so you cannot use variables in it.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is a pre increment.

```
for (( int=1; int <= 100; ++int));
  do
    printf '%s ' $int
  done
```

Use printf to print the numbers in one row instead.

Another example to increment by 2

```
for (( int=1; int <= 100; int+=2));
  do
    printf '%s ' $int
  done
```

Comment: The first code block presents an alternative solution. However, the answer does not address the current question directly -- an explanation on why the original code failed would be desirable.